# Pressing the back arrow on RN app dont refresh connected components to Redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have installed Redux in my app so i can access globale states, but connected components wont update when i press back arrow.
Note that when i modify redux state in a component down in hierarchy and go back components connected wont update but if i go down again they do.

here is my reducer fonction:

```
const initialState = { userData: null };
function updateUserData(state = initialState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_USER_DATA':
      nextState = {
        ...state,
        userData: action.value,
      };
      return nextState || state;
    case 'DELETE_USER_DATA':
      nextState = {
        ...state,
        userData: null,
      };
      return nextState || state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default updateUserData;
```

here i update Redux state:

```
stroreUserData() {
    let userData        = this.props.userData;
    userData.last_name  = this.state.lastName;
    userData.name       = this.state.name;
    userData.birth_date = this.state.birthDate;
    userData.address    = this.state.address;
    userData.tel        = this.state.tel;
    const action = { type: "SAVE_USER_DATA", value: userData };
    this.props.dispatch(action);

  }
```

i connect my components like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
const { userData } = state;  
return {
    userData : userData
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditInfoModal);
```

and access  Redux state like this:

```
const userData = this.props.userData
```

navigation in App.js:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    ChoseResidence: {
      screen: ChoseResidence
    },

    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    Transactions: {
      screen: Transactions
    },
    News: {
      screen: News
    },

    SingleNews: {
      screen: SingleNews
    },
    ZoomBox:{
      screen:ZoomBox
    },
    ResetPassword:{
      screen: ResetPassword
    },
    Setting:{
      screen: Setting
    },
    UserInfos:{
      screen:UserInfos
    }

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',


      },
      headerTitle: (
        <View style={{flex:1.2, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Image
            style={{alignSelf:'center',flex:0.4}}
            source={require('./ressources/Logo-Horizontal.png')}
            resizeMode='contain'
          />
        </View>),
      headerTitleStyle: {
        alignSelf:'center'
      },

    },
  }
);
let Navigation = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

// Render the app container component with the provider around it
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Navigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a little solution i added this to the `componentDidMount` of components i needed to update:

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    () => {
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
)
```

Solution taken from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1617#issuecomment-406875341